# Converting Popmotion example to GreenSock

Tags: javascript, animation, gsap, popmotion

I'm trying to convert this `Popmotion` example to `GreenSock`.

https://codepen.io/popmotion/pen/xVeWmm

```
var SELECTOR      = '.box';
var velocityRange = [-1000, 1000];
var maxRotate     = 30;
var smoothing     = 100;

var box = ui.select(SELECTOR, {
    values: {
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        rotateY: {
            watch: function (actor) {
                return actor.values.x.velocity;
            },
            mapFrom: velocityRange,
            mapTo: [-maxRotate, maxRotate],
            smooth: smoothing
        },
        rotateX: {
            watch: function (actor) {
                return actor.values.y.velocity;
            },
            mapFrom: velocityRange,
            mapTo: [maxRotate, -maxRotate],
            smooth: smoothing
        }
    }
});

var track2D = new ui.Track({
    values: {
        x: {},
        y: {}
    }
});

var springBack = new ui.Simulate({
    simulate: 'spring',
    spring: 500,
    friction: 0.3,
    values: {
        x: 0,
        y: 0
    }
});

$('body').on('touchstart mousedown', SELECTOR, function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();        
    box.start(track2D, e);

});

$('body').on('touchend mouseup', function () {

    box.start(springBack);

});
```

Being a total noob at `GreenSock`, is this easy to do? Does `GreenSock` have actors and simulators?

Comment: Not sure if you have seen GSAP's **[Draggable](http://greensock.com/draggable)** plugin when used along-side **[ThrowProps](https://greensock.com/throwpropsplugin)**.

Comment: @TahirAhmed Yeah that's a really nice start, I'm also looking for the directional tilting thing. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: CSS 3d transforms are definitely available in GSAP but creating an exact replica of this one, requires a bit of work on developer's side. not difficult, but not available out of the box. don't think there is anything pre-built in GSAP which can behave exactly the way you want it to. I will leave you with a few links: https://greensock.com/css3/, http://greensock.com/cube-dial-tutorial. Also, do check out GSAP forums, there are some really smart guys who I believe would definitely help you with this: http://greensock.com/forums/forum/11-gsap/.

Comment: @TahirAhmed thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never used `GreenSock` to make continuous dynamic animations (maybe it is possible, I am not an expert in `GreenSock`). I prefer to left this library to make a specific animation. In the next example, I've tried to replicate the same `Popmotion` effect you have posted using my own calculations and I just use the animation library to return the box to its original place. I think that it can help you in your purpose:

> I've removed the vendor prefixes to make the code easier to read, but the `CodePen` example has the prefixes.

**HTML Code:**

```
<div id="container">

  <div class="box"></div>

</div>
```

**CSS Code**

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    background: #e25875;
    height: 100%;
}

#container {
    height: 100%;
    perspective: 700;
    perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
    position: relative;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    width: 100%;
}

.box {
    background: white;
    border-radius: 4px;
    height: 150px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -75px;
    margin-top: -75px;
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    top: 50%;
    will-change: transform;
    width: 150px;
}
```

**JavaScript Code:**

```
//---Variables
var doc = document,
    box = doc.querySelector(".box"),
    startX = 0,
    startY = 0,
    posX = 0,
    posY = 0,
    speedX = 0,
    speedY = 0,
    obj = {x: 0, y: 0, speedX: 0, speedY: 0};

//---Main Events
box.addEventListener("mousedown", startMove);
doc.addEventListener("mouseup", stopMove);

//---Start the movement
function startMove (evt) {

    startX = evt.pageX;
    startY = evt.pageY;

    //---Add the mouse move events
    doc.addEventListener("mousemove", updatePosition);

}

//---Update variables
function updatePosition (evt) {

    speedX = (evt.pageX - posX) * 5;
    speedY = (evt.pageY - posY) * 5;

    if (speedX < -45) { speedX = -45 }
    if (speedX > 45) { speedX = 45 }
    if (speedY < -45) { speedY = -45 }
    if (speedY > 45) { speedY = 45 }

    posX = evt.pageX;
    posY = evt.pageY;

    obj.x += (posX - startX - obj.x) * .15;
    obj.y += (posY - startY - obj.y) * .15;
    obj.speedX += (speedX - obj.speedX) * .15;
    obj.speedY += (speedY - obj.speedY) * .15; 

    updateTransform();

}

//---Stop movement, returns the box to its place
function stopMove () {

    TweenLite.to(obj, 0.75, {
        ease: Elastic.easeOut.config(1, 0.3),
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        speedX: 0,
        speedY: 0,
        onUpdate: updateTransform
    });

    doc.removeEventListener("mousemove", updatePosition);

}

//---Update the box transformations
function updateTransform () {

    var transformStr = "translate(" + obj.x + "px, " + obj.y + "px) rotateX(" + (-obj.speedY) + "deg) rotateY(" + obj.speedX + "deg)";

    box.style.transform = transformStr;

}
```

Here you have a `CodePen` with a working example.

**EDIT:** I've updated the `CodePen` to work with `Touch Events`.

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/elchininet/full/xgjGGQ)